# When I double-click on the publish content tab on a node, I end up on /user instead

Tags: users, redirection, nodes

This is on a pretty complex site so I have no idea where to start looking for the cause of this behavior.

I have installed the [Publish Content](http://drupal.org/project/publishcontent) module, which creates a little "publish" or "unpublish" tab along with "view" and "edit" on each node, for users that have permission to publish or unpublish content.

When I click on "publish" or "unpublish" once, the expected behavior follows. But if I double-click on that tab (and *only* that tab – others don't do this), then instead of reloading the node, it takes me to my user page.

I tried disabling the devel module but that didn't help. It happens on multiple content types, and as multiple different users with different roles, including user 1.

I have a couple of rule-based redirects in place, but they're only for specific roles and they're only triggered on particular actions (such as login). And none of them redirect to the user's own page.

I have no idea where to start debugging this.

Comment: You have the link that the Publish tab points to? For example: `/publishcontent/publish/node/1234` You get this link, paste it once on your browser, this will publish the unpublished node, then paste it again. This might be the problem, i.e. when you try to publish an already published node, you get redirected to your user page. Just guessing.

Comment: You are right. I don't know why it would redirect to the user page rather than to the node page, though. Thanks.

Comment: That was a pretty wild guess but I guessed right :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you double click, most probable case is the second click will try to use an already used token.

Or it could also be due to the fact that the second click might be translated as trying to publish an already published node.

Comment: Technically I believe it's because when I double-click, it will try to re-use an already-used token, but it's the same effect.

Comment: That's probably also another good case. I'll update the answer.